# Is there a way to add XSD Restrictions to a JAX-WS generated Schema?

Tags: xsd, jax-ws

Looking at the package `javax.jws` and related documentation I didn't find a way to make it to auto generate XSD Restrictions, e.g.

```
<xs:element name="letter">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[a-z]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Is there something basic that I'm missing? And am I asking the wrong question perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're missing anything - you just hit limitations to what is out there. You can do things for enumerations - take a look [here](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/index.html?javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchemaType.html) - but that's pretty much all that resembles what you want and assuming that javax.xml.* is what you referred to as related.